# Binary trees and struct

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I have a binary tree in which each node is a struct. The struct has a string and a number. I need to find the max of the numbers. I've tried

```
int search_max(link h){
    int max = 0;
    if (h->item->acc == max)
        return max;
    if (h->item->acc > max){
        max = h->item->acc;
        return search_max(h->l);
        return search_max(h->r);
    }
    else {
        return search_max(h->l);
        return search_max(h->r);
    }
}
```

But it gives segmentation fault. `link h` is the link of the head of the tree and acc cannot be 0.

Comment: `return search_max(h->l);return search_max(h->r);` The functions exits at the first return, you can't use 2 returns in a row ... (dead code)

Comment: You should include the code for `link` to get more useful feedback. But for one thing, it looks like you should be checking if `h` is `NULL` before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are doing pre-order traversal, but the track of maximum is problematic. For each recursion, you should check and return the maximum node among the current and its two children. Also you didn't check if the node is `NULL`, that's why you saw the crash, since children of the tree's leaf nodes are null nodes. Try this:

```
int search_max(link h) {
    if (h == NULL) return INT_MIN;
    int max = h->item->acc;

    int maxl = search_max(h->l);
    if (max < maxl)
        max = maxl;

    int maxr = search_max(h->r);
    if (max < maxr)
        max = maxr;

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `return` from a function twice in a row, function will exit at first `return`.

Also there's no check for the end of the tree, when on the next iteration `h->l` or `h->r` becomes `NULL` or uninitialized, depending on how you create it. This gives the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another parameter currmax to the function. This will store the current value of maximum to compare against.

```
int search_max(link h, int currmax){
    int max;
    if (h == NULL)
        return currmax;
    else if (h->item->acc > currmax){
        currmax = h->item->acc;

    max = search_max(h->l,currmax);
    if (max > currmax)
       currmax = max;

    max = search_max(h->r, currmax);
    if (max > currmax)
       currmax = max;

    return currmax;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define MY_MAX(a,b) (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b)
typedef struct link
{
    int acc;
    struct link *l, *r;
} link_t;

int search_max(link_t *h, int max)
{
    if (h == NULL) return max;
    if (h->acc > max) max = h->acc;
    max = MY_MAX(search_max(h->l, max), search_max(h->r, max));
    return max;
}
int main(void) {
    link_t root = { 1, 0, 0 };
    link_t l1 = { 2, 0, 0 };
    link_t l2 = { 3, 0, 0 };

    link_t l11 = { 5, 0, 0 };
    link_t l12 = { 1, 0, 0 };
    link_t l21 = { 9, 0, 0 };
    link_t l211 = { 13, 0, 0 };
    link_t l212 = { 0, 0, 0 };
    root.l = &l1;
    root.r = &l2;
    l1.l = &l11;
    l1.r = &l12;
    l2.l = &l21;
    l21.l = &l211;
    l21.r = &l212;
    printf("max [%d]", search_max(&root,0));

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/PKbM0M

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @downvoter Please explain your vote.

Comment: @downvoter any clue?